# Heroku Chatbot App fails to send message to Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es

Interestingly, my Heroku Chatbot (NodeJS) App was working finally for a week. After that, something happened and no message goes through to Dialogflow anymore.

The Heroku NodeJS error message is:

> 2019-11-25T17:09:09.308553+00:00 app[web.1]: error sending message to dialogflow!
>   2019-11-25T17:09:09.308843+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined

The code is:

```
async function sendToDialogFlow(sender, textString, params) {
    sendTypingOn(sender);
    try {
        const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(
            config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
            sessionIds.get(sender)
        );

        const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
                text: {
                    text: textString,
                    languageCode: config.DF_LANGUAGE_CODE,
                },
            },
            queryParams: {
                payload: {
                    data: params
                }
            }
        };
        const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
        const result = responses[0].queryResult;
        handleDialogFlowResponse(sender, result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(' error sending message to dialogflow! ');
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

I can attach any additional info on request.

Please someone try to help me

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/jschnurr/botkit-middleware-dialogflow/issues/13 would seem to indicate it's a missing project ID?

Comment: project ID is stored by Heroku in the config vars section, and it is there ever since the first time...

Comment: Hi cokeman19 - hey by any chance did you resolve this issue?